# How to unpack a json file into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, influxdb-python

I am having issues unpacking my JSON file on localhost into a structured pandas DataFrame

I have tried several techniques but I am not getting the dataframe to look like a pandas timeframe so that I can address the columns easily.

I first started by:

```
WaterTrainingData_request = Request('http://localhost:9092/kapacitor/v1/tasks/WaterTrainingData/recent')
WaterTrainingData_response = urlopen(WaterTrainingData_request)
WaterTrainingData_read_data = WaterTrainingData_response.read()
WaterTrainingData_file = json.loads(WaterTrainingData_read_data)
json_normalize(WaterTrainingData_file)

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(list(WaterTrainingData_file.items()))
print(dfObj)
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to get it in a structured manner.

Here is my desired output:

```
                            Tp    Cl    pH  Redox   Leit  Trueb   Cl_2      Fm    Fm_2  EVENT
Time
2016-02-15 11:54:00+00:00  4.4  0.14  8.38  755.0  232.0  0.009  0.110  1428.0  1020.0  False
2016-02-15 11:55:00+00:00  4.4  0.14  8.38  755.0  232.0  0.009  0.111  1436.0  1018.0  False
2016-02-15 11:56:00+00:00  4.4  0.14  8.38  755.0  232.0  0.014  0.113  1471.0  1019.0  False
2016-02-15 11:57:00+00:00  4.4  0.14  8.37  755.0  232.0  0.015  0.111  1457.0  1015.0  False
2016-02-15 11:58:00+00:00  4.4  0.14  8.38  755.0  232.0  0.013  0.111  1476.0  1019.0  False
...                        ...   ...   ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...     ...    ...
2016-05-10 10:43:00+00:00  5.1  0.14  8.49  755.0  210.0  0.026  0.095  1711.0  1041.0  False
2016-05-10 10:44:00+00:00  5.1  0.14  8.49  754.0  210.0  0.026  0.095  1732.0  1038.0  False
2016-05-10 10:45:00+00:00  5.1  0.15  8.49  754.0  210.0  0.026  0.095  1711.0  1040.0  False
2016-05-10 10:46:00+00:00  5.1  0.15  8.49  756.0  210.0  0.026  0.095  1715.0  1041.0  False
2016-05-10 10:47:00+00:00  5.1  0.15  8.49  755.0  210.0  0.027  0.095  1694.0  1035.0  False
```

Here is what the Json file looks like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DncBR.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DncBR.png

I also uploaded the JSON file here: https://gofile.io/?c=92CLRR

Comment: can you post the data?

Comment: Sure. Can I send you the json file?

Comment: you can upload it using https://gofile.io/?t=uploadFiles

Comment: Here: https://gofile.io/?c=92CLRR

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Code/data should be included as text in the post itself, not as images. Please share **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve]. You haven't said what exactly is wrong with the current code, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
with open('recent.json') as json_file:
     data = json.load(json_file)

dfObj = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

Comment: it gives this 0  series  {'name': 'waterDataTraining', 'columns': ['tim...

Comment: Doesn't give me the desired output, unfortunately.